# UI viewcontroller Navigation bar is black

Tags: swift3, navigationbar

I can't change the colour of my navigation bar to transparent.  All the other view controllers in my project are fine, only this one.  This particular view controller has a scroll view and it is presented by Segue.view

I use the following code in viewDidLoad()

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

[image]

This is the identity inspector for the view controller

[image]

Comment: if i change the following line to FALSE then the navigationbar color becomes white            
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  My background image was inside my View.  I put it in the wrong place. see below for correct way

[image]